# Cifrado del César Javascript

Tags: javascript

Me piden que haga un cifrado del césar para un mensaje cualquiera. Me planteo tener una matriz con las letras en posición originales y otra matriz con las letras cambiadas de posición, así según busco la posición de cada pletra en la primera matriz y la cambio por la letra de la misma posición del segundo matriz que tendrá una constante de desplazamiento de 2. El tema es que solo me cifra la primera y la última letra del mensaje, las demás me las muestra como .indefinidas. Muestra: bundefinedundefinedundefineda .Cuando debería mostrar: bedca

```js
var mensaje = "ecbad"
var textoPlano = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var textoCifrado = ["c","d","e","a","b"];
var cont = 0;
var mensajeCifrado = "";
var longMensaje = mensaje.length;
for (cont;cont<longMensaje;cont++) {
 letra = mensaje.substr(cont,cont+1);
 posTextoPlano = textoPlano.indexOf(letra);
 mensajeCifrado += textoCifrado[posTextoPlano];
}
document.querySelector(".demo1").innerHTML = mensajeCifrado;
```

Comment: var mensaje = "ecbad"
var textoPlano = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var textoCifrado = ["c","d","e","a","b"];
var cont = 0;
var mensajeCifrado = "";
var longMensaje = mensaje.length;
for (cont;cont<longMensaje;cont++) {
 letra = mensaje.substr(cont,cont+1);
 posTextoPlano = textoPlano.indexOf(letra);
 mensajeCifrado += textoCifrado[posTextoPlano];
}
document.querySelector(".demo1").innerHTML = mensajeCifrado;

Comment: Agrega tu codigo editando la pregunta, no como un comentario.

Comment: Entiendo. Ya lo he puesto. Al ser nuevo en el foro aún tengo lagunas en cuanto a la mecánica de funcionamiento de éste. Gracias.

Comment: Acabo de ver esto en codepen. A lo mejor te puede ayudar: [Caesar Cipher](https://codepen.io/youfoundron/pen/dvGqrw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la cadena como un array y accesar cada letra con corchetes asi:

```js
var mensaje = "ecbad"
var textoPlano = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var textoCifrado = ["c","d","e","a","b"];
var mensajeCifrado = "";

for (var i=0; i<mensaje.length; i++) {
 letra = mensaje[i];
 posTextoPlano = textoPlano.indexOf(letra);
 mensajeCifrado += textoCifrado[posTextoPlano];
}
document.querySelector(".demo1").innerHTML = mensajeCifrado;
```

```html
<div class="demo1"></div>
```